# Proof Verification: identifying quotient of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, modules

Let $M$ be $R$ module, $M_1,M_2,S$ be $R$ submodules of $M$ such that $M_1\subset M_2$.

Let $N_1$ be the $R$ submodule of $M$ generated by $M_1$ and $S$, let $N_2$ be the $R$ submodule of $M$ generated by $M_2$ and $S$.

Is $N_2/N_1\subset M_2/M_1$?

My attempt: $N_2/N_1=\{x+N_1:x\in N_2\}$. If $x+N_1$ is an element of $N_2/N_1$, then we may write $x=r_1m_2+r_2s$ for some $r_1,r_2\in R$ and $m_2\in M_2,s\in S$. So $x+N_1=r_1m_2+N_1$ as $r_2s\in N_1$. Also, for any $x\in M_2$, we have $x\in N_2$, so $x+N_1\in N_2/N_1$. So we may re-write $N_2/N_1$ as $\{x+N_1:x\in M_2\}$. With this new expression, the map $f: N_2/N_1\to M_2/M_1$ given by $x+N_1\to x+M_1$ makes sense.

$f$ is injective because $f(x+N_1)=0+M_1$ implies $x+M_1=M_1$, so $x\in M_1$, so $x\in N_1$, so $x+N_1=N_1$.

Comment: Consider $R = \Bbb R, M = \Bbb R^3, M_1$ the $x$-axis, $M_2$ the plane $z = 0$, $S$ the $z$-axis. Then $N_1$ is the plane $y = 0$ and $N_2 = M = \Bbb R^3$. $N_2/N_1$ consists of the planes parallel to $y = 0$ and is equivalent to the $y$-axis. $M_2/M_1$ consists of lines with $z = 0$ and parallel to the $y$-axis, and is also equivalent to the $y$-axis. So $N_2/N_1$ and $M_2/M_1$ are isomorphic submodules, but as sets, neither is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments noted, the statement is false, so the proof if invalid. Here's some notes on your proof:

- You would only need to write $x=m_2+s$. The scalars of $R$ are not necessary (since, for example, $r_1m_2$ is just another element in $M_2$, so you could just call it $m_2$ to begin with).
- You said that for any $x\in M_2$, we have $x\in N_2$, which is correct, but that does not mean that $N_2/N_1=\{x+N_1:x\in M_2\}$. In order for this to be true, we would also need that if $x\in N_2$, then $x\in M_2$ (which is not the case here).
- The justification that $f:N_2/N_1\to M_2/M_1$ "makes sense" is not clear. We have a few issues in regards to this function being well-defined. That is $x=m_2+s\in N_2$ is not necessarily a unique representation of $x$. There may be another way that $x$ could be represented, e.g., $x=m_2'+s'$. Moreover, $x+N_1\in N_2/N_1$ is not a unique way to write this element, there may be some other element $x'\in N_2$ such that $x+N_1=x'+N_1$. We would need to make sure that all of these different ways to represent elements in $N_2/N_1$ all map to the same element in $M_2/M_1$.